# IIS: Removing Trailing Dots from URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I want to remove trailing dots such as `...` from all urls on IIS. I tried to use the following rule:

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingDots" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^.]*)\.+$" />
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This works as expected on my local PC but not on my website.

For example I expected `/fruits/apple...` to be redirected to `/fruits/apple` but no redirect happens.

Thanks

Comment: `.` does not need to be escaped when it's inside a `[]` character class.

Comment: @Amber Thanks. I have unescaped `.` But still it does not work on my site. Redirection does not happen on both `/fruits/apple...` and `/fruits/..`

Comment: Why on earth do you want to support URLs with trailing dots? That's not even remotely a common thing.

Comment: @KevinBallard actually a handful of the links to my site shown in Google Webmaster Tools have trailing dots in them which actually point to 404 pages

Comment: @erfan: I can imagine showing the text of a link with trailing dots if its long, but I have a hard time believing the hyperlink itself has trailing dots.

Comment: @KevinBallard It happens - sometimes people just construct their links to your site wrong. I'm dealing with the same issue on one of our sites right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're requiring that everything before the trailing dots be completely devoid of dots. You might try something like

```
<match url="^(.*[^.])\.+$" />
```

This will match any number of characters, followed by a single non-dot character (as part of the capture), followed by dots (which aren't captured).

That said, I don't understand why you even want this. URLs with trailing dots are not even remotely a common thing to have.

Comment: thanks! this also works with my site at `localhost` but not at my webhost. may be this is due to the fact that my localhost is on IIS 7.5 and my webhost is on IIS 7

Comment: @erfan: Do you have the right URL Rewrite engine turned on for IIS 7? Sounds like it includes 2 (one for regex, one for wildcards)